# Protocol Buffers between two different languages

Tags: go, .net-core, protocol-buffers, grpc, protobuf-net

We are using Golang and .NET Core for our inter-communication microservices infrastructure.
All the data across the services are coming based on Protobuffs Protocols that we have created.
Here is an example of one of our Protobuffs:

```
syntax = "proto3";
package Protos;
option csharp_namespace = "Protos";
option go_package="Protos";
message EventMessage {
    string actionType = 1;
    string payload = 2;
    bool auditIsActive = 3;
}
```

Golang is working well and the service is generating the content as needed and sending it to the SQS queue, once that happens the .NET core service is getting the data and trying to serialize it.

Here are the contents of the SQS message example:

```
{"@type":"type.googleapis.com/Protos.EventMessage","actionType":"PushPayload","payload":"<<INTERNAL>>"}
```

But we are getting an Exception that saying the wire-type is not defined as mentioned below:

```
Google.Protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException: Protocol message contained a tag with an invalid wire type.
   at Google.Protobuf.UnknownFieldSet.MergeFieldFrom(CodedInputStream input)
   at Google.Protobuf.UnknownFieldSet.MergeFieldFrom(CodedInputStream input)
   at Google.Protobuf.UnknownFieldSet.MergeFieldFrom(UnknownFieldSet unknownFields, CodedInputStream input)
   at Protos.EventMessage.MergeFrom(CodedInputStream input) in /Users/maordavidzon/projects/github_connector/GithubConnector/GithubConnector/obj/Debug/netcoreapp3.0/EventMessage.cs:line 232
   at Google.Protobuf.MessageExtensions.MergeFrom(IMessage message, Byte[] data, Boolean discardUnknownFields, ExtensionRegistry registry)
   at Google.Protobuf.MessageParser`1.ParseFrom(Byte[] data)
```

The Proto file is exactly the same in both of the services.

Is there any potential missing options or property that we need to add?

Comment: The most likely cause of this is incorrect treatment of binary payloads; do you have an example binary payload? Note that you can verify a payload using https://protogen.marcgravell.com/decode - classic ways to break a binary payload include: 1) "encoding" (air quotes intentional) it to text by running it backwards through a text-encoding (you should use base-64 or hex etc if you need to pass it as text, not a text encoding in reverse), 2) using C-style string (nul-terminated) APIs (don't), or 3) truncating/over-padding the payload (protobuf is not self-terminating)

Comment: from the question, it looks like you're passing protobuf inside JSON, so: my money is on the first option above: I'd happily speculate that you've encoded it it text (for the JSON) incorrectly. Until you can get back to the original bytes before calling `ParseFrom`, all other considerations are meangless

Comment: oh! (light comes on) are you using the JSON version of protobuf? if so; yeah, you need to use the JSON parse API; there are two formats for protobuf - usually, people mean the binary one, and `ParseFrom(byte[])` is for the binary one. If you're using the JSON data format, you'll need to use the JSON parse API. Is there a `ParseFromJson` or similar? or one that takes a `string`? Edit: checking the docs, `ParseJson`: https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/csharp/class/google/protobuf/message-parser

Answer (score 5):

It looks like you're using the JSON format rather than the binary format. In that case, [you want `ParseJson(string json)`, not `ParseFrom(byte[] data)`](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/csharp/class/google/protobuf/message-parser).

Note: the binary format is more efficient, if that matters to you. It also has better support across protobuf libraries / tools.

Answer (score 0):

Basically there are two possible scenarios, or your protos files generated for .NET and GoLang are not in the same version or your data has been corrupted while transferring between GoLang and .NET application.

Protobuf is a binary protocol, check if you have any http filter or anything else that can change incoming or outgoing stream of bytes.

Comment: "Protobuf is a binary protocol" - we commonly think of it as such (my protobuf library only supports this mode), but there *is* a JSON variant, and it looks like the OP is using the JSON variant.